# zpl code with VB 2008-20010

Tags: printing, vb6

I have code at zpl language ,I need put these code in VB6 to print the Barcode 39 ,when click on the button I need print the code to Zebra Printer as barcode 39 ,The cood is

^XA^CFD^LH0,0^PR6^FS
^FWN^FS
^FX

^FO10,10^A0N,30^FDPART(P)P01529014BL^FS

^FO10,40^BY2,3^B3N,N,50,N,N^FD5HR071D5AE^FS
^FO10,100^A0N,30^FDWD GBOX ASY SE/SXT BLACK^FS
^FO220,130^A0N,35^FDCUS.PART#^FS
^FO420,40^A0N,15^FDMAYCO INTERNATIONAL^FS

^FO10,160^A0N,20^FDSERIL^FS
^FO80,160^A0N,20^FR^SN12345678,1,Y^FS

^PQ1,0,1,Y^FS
^XZ

please if some body print this code in vb6 to Zebra printer can help me to connect this code with vb and print  as text because these printer understand just with zpl as text not as graphic

thank you